# Is there any way to capture the input file name of multiple parquet files read in with a wildcard in pandas/awswrangler?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parquet, aws-data-wrangler

This is the exact python analogue of the following Spark question:

[Is there any way to capture the input file name of multiple parquet files read in with a wildcard in Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57171568/is-there-any-way-to-capture-the-input-file-name-of-multiple-parquet-files-read-i)

I am reading in a wildcard list of parquet files using (variously) pandas and awswrangler.

Is there a way to retrieve a column containing the original filename of each row loaded into the eventual combined dataframe, exactly as per the Spark version of this quesiton?

Update: This is possibly a way to do it - [Reading DataFrames saved as parquet with pyarrow, save filenames in columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63474481/reading-dataframes-saved-as-parquet-with-pyarrow-save-filenames-in-columns)

Update2: The present question is the reverse of https://stackoverflow.com/a/59682461/1021819

Comment: Read [How to create a Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @jtlz2 -- would appreciate some runnable code to generate example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add the filename as a new column to each dataframe as you load them. For example, here is how to do this with a set of CSV files since that is easier to run as an example. You'll follow a similar pattern for parquet files.

```py
from pathlib import Path

import pandas as pd

# write a couple fake csv files to our disk as examples
Path("csv1.csv").write_text("a,b\n1,2\n1,2")
Path("csv2.csv").write_text("b,c\n3,4\n3,4")

all_dfs = []

# for every csv file that we want to load
for f in Path(".").glob("csv*.csv"):
    
    # read the csv
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    
    # add a filename column to the dataframe
    df["filename"] = f.name
    
    # store the dataframe to concat later
    all_dfs.append(df)
    
# put together the dataframes for each file
pd.concat(all_dfs)
#>      a  b  filename    c
#> 0  1.0  2  csv1.csv  NaN
#> 1  1.0  2  csv1.csv  NaN
#> 0  NaN  3  csv2.csv  4.0
#> 1  NaN  3  csv2.csv  4.0
```